# How can I use Laravel form model binding with bootstrap?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, model, laravel-4

I am trying to display a bootstrap formatted form bound to my User model. However, the form-model binding seems to only work out when I use input fields that are not formatted with bootstrap styles.

Here is one  without the bootstrap class, which perfectly displays what I have in my db when I open my form with:

```
{{ Form::model($user) }}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Vorname:')}}
{{ Form::text('name')}}
```

Here is the second input of this form, now with the bootstrap class. This one does not display the db content.

```
{{ Form::label('sirname', 'Nachname:')}}
{{ Form::text('sirname', '', array('class'=>'form-control'))}}
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to use form-model binding and styling the inputs with bootstrap classes at the same time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: sirname is not spelled correctly. In English, last name is written as 'surname'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => 'xyz')) }}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Vorname:')}}
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

{{ Form::label('sirname', 'Nachname:')}}
{{ Form::text('sirname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

if you use form model, do not forget to close it.

Comment: It works! However, it is not intuitive at all. If you provide an empty string you get an empty field, if you provide null you get a compiled one... Strange.

Comment: How is it meant to work for checkboxes? In my form, it works with one argument, but as soon as I add null and a CSS class in an array, it stops binding.

Comment: @MattFletcher https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons